# can't access indexer of a property in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a property **Cmd** defined as follows

```
Private _cmd As ADODB.Command

Public ReadOnly Property Cmd() As ADODB.Command
    Get
        Cmd = _cmd
    End Get
End Property
```

However, when I try to use it like this:

```
y = x.Cmd("abc")
```

I get:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parameters' accepts this
>   number of arguments.

However, this works:

```
y = (x.Cmd)("abc")
```

Can I change my property definition so that the user does not need the parens?

Comment: Does the class inherit from another class?  Are there more indexers?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to binarycoder´s solution, I suggest you another one. If you want to use your code in this way:

```
y = x.Cmd("abc")
```

You can change your Cmd property to look like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Cmd(ByVal parameterName As String) As ADODB.Command
        Get
            Return _cmd.Parameters(parameterName)
        End Get
End Property
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I change my property definition so
>   that the user does not need the
>   parens?

No. The crux of the issue is that the default property (`Parameters`) is not an indexed property but instead returns an `ADODB.Parameters` object. Although `ADODB.Parameters` is has indexed `Item` property, it is one level too deep. Since you can't change `ADODB`, you might consider adding a helper method. You can then use this method instead of your property.

```
Public Function CmdParameter(ByVal parameterName As String) As ADODB.Parameter
    Return Cmd.Parameters(parameterName)
End Function
```